# jQuery select attributes into an array

Tags: jquery

What's the most elegant way to get this array

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

out of this list

```
<ul>  
    <li value="10">Item One</li>
    <li value="20">Item Two</li>
    <li value="30">Item three</li>
    <li value="40">Item Four</li>
    <li value="50">Item Five</li>
</ul>
```

using jQuery.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

****edit****

*ok the glove has been thrown down...*

```
var elements = (document.getElementsByTagName('li'));
var vals = [];
for(var i=0;typeof(elements[i])!='undefined';vals.push(elements[i++].getAttribute('value')));
```

no library 3 lines of code...

**epicly faster**

[image]

---

```
var myVals = [];
$('li','ul').each(function(){
  myVals.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

*and using jquery's map function...*

```
var myVals = [];
$('li','ul').map(function(){
  myVals.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

and they are both equally as fast..
http://jsperf.com/testing-stuff
[image]

Comment: map would not really make sense... seeing as you are just extracting values and not DOM elements

Comment: @samccone But can return values :p

Comment: ha ok you win.. if we want to save like 14 characters we can do it that way :)

Comment: absolutely it is faster! And a great solution. I'd use pure javascript  most of the time too. However, the question asked for a jQuery solution.

Comment: @natedavisolds that is why I provided all the solutions :)

Comment: +1, it's crazy how lower-level code can be faster! Elegance comes at a price.

Comment: Shouldn't you return the value in the mapping-function? I imagine this would be faster since your solution effectively populates two arrays, and throws away the second.

SO, do something like:
`var values = $.map($("li[value]"), function(li) {
    return $(li).attr("value");
 });
`

Comment: @Alexis makes a good point. The efficient syntax can be simply: `$('li','ul').map(function() {return this.attr('value');})`.

Comment: .. in my previous comment, might need to be `$(this).attr(` instead of `this.attr(`.

Answer (score 33):

I think that map works just fine.. just not in the chain.

```
var vals = $.map($("li[value]"), function(li) {
    return $(li).attr("value");
});
```

Comment: @samccone interesting that "no library" is preferred for a question specifically asking for a solution "using jquery".

Comment: This is also the "most elegant" as the question poses. Speed is irrelevant for such a small run, but still nice to see.

Answer (score 8):

```
var outVal = [];
$('ul li').each(function(idx, el){
    outVal.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Speaking of elegant code, we can get a better solution using Underscore in combination with jQuery:

```
_($('ul li').toArray()).map(function(e) { return e.value })
```

And while we're at it, why not dump Javascript for CoffeeScript:

```
_($('ul li').toArray()).map (e) -> e.value
```

;-)

Comment: jQuery already has `$.map` and `.map` (works sorta like flatmap). But +1 for using a map.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that jQuery had that one, I'm totally hooked on Underscore it seems!

Comment: ha @nicolas ... nice I got mine down to 3 lines and no libraries :)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, what's _? I've never seen it before!

Comment: It's the Underscore.js function, an awesome library that I hope will become as common as jQuery one day: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

Comment: Underscore looks nice, more functional goodness, looks like Scala in JavaScript to me (I'm a functional newbie, BTW).

Comment: Note: less lines is not always better