# Get text of an xml with a certain attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I get this xml in `$(c)`:

```
<response name="GetStatistics"><chart chart_num="0">500</chart><chart chart_num="1">1000</chart></response>
```

and I'm trying to get chart's values.

I tried:

```
var val = $(c).find('command[chart_num='+j+']').text();
alert ('command[chart_num='+j+'] ' + val);
```

But in the alert I don't get value of `val` at all.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Change `command` to `chart` ?

Comment: thanks...
my mistake, sorry

Comment: You might consider adding the `jquery` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

So something like:

```
var val = $(c).find('chart[char_num=' + j + ']').text();
```

**edit:**

Sorry, you were using the attribute selector.  The issue is switching command to chart as noted in the comment on the question.

Comment: Wrong syntax with brackets, and you forgot the context .

Answer (score 0):

First, use **jQuery's** [parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) function to obtain your XML document:

```
var xml = "<response name='GetStatistics'>"
  + "<chart chart_num='0'>500</chart>"
  + "<chart chart_num='1'>1000</chart>"
  + "</response>";

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
```

Then, use the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select a `chart` element by its `chart_num` attribute:

```
var j = 1;
var chartNumValue = $xml.find('chart[chart_num=' + j + ']').text();
// chartNumValue = 1000
```

Also, you may find it useful to [obtain an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055187/1497596) of all of your `chart_num` attribute values:

```
var $charts = $xml.find('chart');

var chartNums = $.map($charts, function(el) {
    return $(el).attr("chart_num");
});
```